# Python class with datetime.now() when instantiated

Tags: python, class, datetime

I want a Class attribute which sets `datetime.now()` when the a new instance of the class is instantiated.  With this code, `MyThing.created` seems to always be when `MyThing` is imported, as opposed to when `mt` is instantiated.

```
from datetime import datetime

class MyThing:
    __init__(self, created=datetime.now()):
        self.created = created

MyThing.created
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 5, 10, 54, 24, 865791)

mt = MyThing()
mt.created
datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 5, 10, 54, 24, 865791)
```

How can I do it so that `created` is when `mt` is instantiated, as opposed to `MyThing`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Default values for function parameters are computed once, when the function is defined.  They are not re-evaluated when the function is called.  Typically, you'd use `None` as the default value, and test for it in the body:

```
def __init__(self, created=None):
    self.created = created or datetime.now()
```

Even better, it looks like maybe you don't want to ever pass a created date into the constructor, in which case:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.created = datetime.now()
```

Comment: Nice to know both alternatives for either case.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Don't set it in the parameters as they are members of the function itself since everything is a first class object.

```
class MyThing:
    __init__(self, created=None):
        self.created = created
        if created is None:
            self.created = datetime.now()
```

Comment: Alternately, ``self.created = datetime.now() if created is None else created``

Comment: I just hate the double assignment. :)